# Why is the collector region doped?

Tags: transistors, bjt, junction, depletion-region, linear-region

As long as within the active region the collector-emitter junction is reverse biased, is there a purpose for which the collector must be doped? Moreover, not only that it is doped, but it is moderately doped, thus more than slightly doped like the base region.

Comment: For low resistance for efficiency, as much for creating the junction with the base.

Comment: If the collector is not doped the resistance is lower.

Comment: @pauk no, undoped silicon is (effectively) an insulator.

Comment: If the collector wasn't doped the transistor wouldn't work.

Comment: Typically the base is more heavliy doped than the collector, and I wouldnt consider the base "slightly" doped, its more into "moderate" territory.

Comment: @MarcusMüller True, neither a reverse-biased diode is a conductor.

Comment: @pauk I don't fully get what you're telling me there?

Comment: ``@pauk no, undoped silicon is (effectively) an insulator``, indeed, undoped silicon is not a very good conductor, BUT, here we talk about junctions because the carriers must pass through the base-collector region, which is in during the active region always REVERSE biased, thus, I find it more efficient to slightly dope the collector region, or even not to dope it, as long as the more doped the collector is the harder for the carriers to cross the base-collector junction will be.

Comment: There were once transistors that had an intrinsic region in them (PNIP and NPIN transistors), though I'm not sure what the advantage of that was. Possibly speed.

Comment: @Matt I know what pin diodes are, I'm talking about npin and pnip transistors, which I know existed, but which i don't think have been used in decades.

Comment: @Hearth Oh, yes. I misread that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The essence of transistor behavior in the active region is as follows.

- The base-collector pn junction is reverse biased
- majority carriers have a difficult time crossing a reverse biased pn junction
- minority carriers easily cross a reverse biased pn junction
- unless the emitter injects minority carriers into the base, there are few minority carriers in the base
- when the base-emitter pn junction is forward biased, majority carriers from the emitter cross the base-emitter junction into the base, where they become minority carriers, (where they easily cross over the reverse biased base-collector junction).

Now:

> As long as within the active region the collector-emitter junction is reverse biased, is there a purpose for which the collector must be doped?

The conductivity of the collector depends upon doping. Undoped silicon is a poor conductor.

> Moreover, not only that it is doped, but it is moderately doped, thus more than slightly doped like the base region.

The base is lightly doped to reduce the number of majority carriers in the base. The concentration of majority carriers is directly related to the doping concentration. The higher the concentration of majority carriers, the greater the chance of the minority carriers recombine in the base with majority carriers. This increases base current, and decreases collector current.

The collector is doped less than the emitter to make the transistor asymmetric. The more symmetrical a transistor, the poorer it performs in the forward active region (but the better it performs in the reverse active region).

Those are the reasons why the base and collector are both doped less strongly than the emitter. Why the base might be doped even less than the collector I do not currently know. Perhaps someone with more expertise in transistor design can answer.

Comment: Thus, the minority carriers could pass through a reverse-biased junction faster than through an undoped semiconductor?

Comment: @pauk If by "faster" you mean higher current, I think the answer is yes.

Comment: Thanks. Also, could you explain to me why is the collector doped "heavier" than the base?

Comment: I'm not an expert on transistor design, but I believe the reason is as follows. Minority carriers in the base will tend to recombine with the majority carriers in the base. One doesn't want that. One wants the minority carriers to cross the base and enter the collector. So, to keep the number of majority carriers down, the base is only lightly doped. Also, it is physically thin, so that minority carriers can cross it quickly before they recombine. The number of majority carriers in the base is directly related to the doping concentration. Maybe someone more expert can explain more fully?